# Choose account for Facebook android login?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I've followed the Facebook dev login tutorial for *Android*, to get my app to the point that the login/logout widget (from FB) works and I can login and log out of my Facebook account. However, it is dependent on my android **Facebook application** account logged in at the time.

I can't actually enter login details from within my app if I logout and try relog- it automatically just logs me in with my account? So it just uses which ever one is logged in, with the android Facebook app. If I log out of the android FB app it brings up the login screen (asking for details) in my app, but I don't want to have to do that. Is there anyway get my app to ask for login details if I logout from within the app?

I've looked at [How to log in with other facebook account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453753/how-to-log-in-with-other-facebook-account) and [How to disable Sandbox Mode for app in new Facebook Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706322/how-to-disable-sandbox-mode-for-app-in-new-facebook-developer) but had no luck.

Comment: No there is no way to do that. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well, if someone wants to use the app (but not on their phone), it would be much easier if they could just login using their credentials from within my app, as opposed to logging their friend out of their actual Facebook App just to use my app.